# How to fix' NULL problem with foreach loop of the doParallel package'

Tags: r

Currently working on the software Monolix (software for estimating the parameters of mathematical models). I am currently using the R functions available for this software. It achieves exactly the same as it is possible to achieve with the UI.

To run the functions under R, it is necessary to submit a file corresponding to the model that we want to test. So I created 100 files in mlxtran format that are exactly the same for the design of the model, they only differ on the dataset to be processed.

At first I managed to realize, my operations on a single file mlxtran, it worked. Then, i done it thanks to a for loop to perform the analysis on the 100 files in my list, it worked. The problem comes when I have to do this by parallelizing my code via the dopar function of the foreach loop.

```
#Version that works
library(lixoftConnectors)
initializeLixoftConnectors(software = "monolix")
library(doParallel)
library(dplyr)

#Put my 100 mlxtran in a list
ldfRec <- dir(pattern = "*.mlxtran")

#Version fonctionnant avec un seul
loadProject(ldfRec[1])
runScenario()
ResultPopParameters<-getEstimatedPopulationParameters()
ResultPopParameters

#Version that does not work

cl <- detectCores() %>% -1 %>% makeCluster
registerDoParallel(cl)

#Put my 100 mlxtran in a list
ldfRec <- dir(pattern = "*.mlxtran")

resultatsForEach<-foreach(z=1:100, .packages=c("lixoftConnectors","dplyr","doParallel")) %dopar% {

  loadProject(ldfRec[z])
  runScenario()
  ResultPopParameters<-getEstimatedPopulationParameters()
  ResultsStandardErrors<-getEstimatedStandardErrors()
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

I expect the output for all my files. The results for one run are like that:

ka_pop  1.56    V_pop  2.4     ....

It's a list with all the estimation for each parameter of my model.

For now, with the foreach loop i hava a resultForEach list with only NULL value.

I apologize for the grammatical errors, Thanking you

Comment: I suggest you study the package vignettes. foreach is more similar to lapply loops than to for loops. Their body needs a "return" value.

Comment: On the last line, ResultsStandardErrors<-getEstimatedStandardErrors() , if you want this passing back in to resultatsforEach, then just paste:   return(getEstimatedStandardErrors()).